# how to traverse all edges efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I need to traverse all edges in a graph and get a collection of edges without repetition.
I used DFS and keep adding edges to collection as following.

```
   procedure DFS(G,v):
   label v as discovered
   for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
   {
           addEdge(v,w);              //get edges 
           if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
              recursively call DFS(G,w)
   }
```

but since it should not have repetition of edges, I need to do some checking in 
'addEdges'.

```
  addEdges(v,w)
  {
    if either  v or w is not in HashTble(nodes) /
       {
         add edge(v,w) to collection(edges)
         add v and w to HashTble(nodes)
       } 
    else
       {  //both v and w in HashTble(nodes)
          if edge(v,w) is not in collection(edges)
             add edge(v,w) to collection(edges)
       }
  }
```

That is how I did it. The problem is that the graph can be very big and in such graph 'addEdges' consuming time, since it has to check in the collection some times.

Is there any other way i can do this faster? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move the `if` for label testing outside the `for` loop and you should never traverse an edge twice (*if v is labelled, return;*).

Comment: @Holt. If I just move as you say, i might miss some edges, since DFS don't visit all edges. I think the answer given below solves my problem. :)

Comment: You won't miss anything since this is basically the same as your code (which I misread or I would not have proposed such answer... ).

Comment: @Holt i did not understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to check if you've seen the edge before. Since you don't visit a node twice, you won't be able to have the same edge twice (that is if the graph is directed).

If your graph is undirected then you will add every edge(u,v) twice (once when you visit u and again when you visits v). To get rid of this you can add the constraint that you only add an edge if u < v.

All in all the algo should look like:

```
procedure DFS(G,v):
label v as discovered
for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
{
       add edge(v,w) to output edges   
       if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
          recursively call DFS(G,w)
}
```

Or if you have an undirected graph:

```
procedure DFS(G,v):
label v as discovered
for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
{
       if (v < w) add edge(v,w) to output edges
       if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
          recursively call DFS(G,w)
}
```

Comment: My graph is undirected one. Seems that constraint you recommended is a good trick. Thank you, I will try it.